# NumPy vectorize pyfunc to expand array into arguments

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have an array of rectangular coordinates with the shape `Ax2`, where `A` is an arbitrary number. Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
>>> np.arange(20).reshape(10, 2)
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11],
       [12, 13],
       [14, 15],
       [16, 17],
       [18, 19]])
```

I want to convert each array of two values along axis 0 into an array of polar coordinates (also two values). So the end array should also have the shape `Ax2`. Here's an example of what I want as output:

```
>>> a = np.arange(20).reshape(10, 2)
>>> toPolar(a)
[[ 1.          1.57079633]
 [ 3.60555128  0.98279372]
 [ 6.40312424  0.89605538]
 [ 9.21954446  0.86217005]
 [12.04159458  0.84415399]
 [14.86606875  0.83298127]
 [17.69180601  0.82537685]
 [20.51828453  0.81986726]
 [23.34523506  0.81569192]
 [26.17250466  0.81241861]]
```

I got the following code to work by splitting the array by columns to get an array of x-values and y-values, then passing both those arrays to a vectorized form of a generic rectangular to polar coordinate function. However, that last step gives an array with the shape `2xA`, so I needed to transpose it back into `Ax2`:

```
def toPolar(arr):
    def rect2polar(x, y):
        r = math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
        ang = math.atan2(y, x)
        return (r, ang)

    vect = np.vectorize(rect2polar)
    p = vect(r[:, 0], r[:, 1])  # splits coords up and returns in 2x10 array
    p = np.transpose(p)  # converts from 2x10 back to 10x2
    return p
```

I would think that it's slow to split up the array only to then transpose it again.

Is there any way to skip the transpose step by having `np.vectorize` create a function that takes an array as input, so then I could run the vectorized function along axis 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer part of your question, unfortunately I don't think it's possible to apply a function directly to your array "along axis 0" without incurring some kind of (maybe hidden) python level loop. The issue is that most of the useful numpy builtin functions take their arguments separately, and not along a dimension in an array.

In that sense, it may be more natural to work with your data not as a `A x 2` shaped array, but as a pair of `x, y` variables each of shape `A`:

```
>>> x = np.arange(0, 20, 2)
>>> y = np.arange(1, 20, 2)
>>> x
array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18])
>>> y
array([ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19])
```

The relevant numpy functions for converting to polar are [`np.hypot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hypot.html) and [`np.arctan2`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html). Simply:

```
>>> r = np.hypot(y, x)
>>> theta = np.arctan2(y, x)
>>> r
array([ 1.        ,  3.60555128,  6.40312424,  9.21954446, 12.04159458,
       14.86606875, 17.69180601, 20.51828453, 23.34523506, 26.17250466])
>>> theta
array([1.57079633, 0.98279372, 0.89605538, 0.86217005, 0.84415399,
       0.83298127, 0.82537685, 0.81986726, 0.81569192, 0.81241861])
```

That being said, there are ways to fiddle with the shapes so that they align the way you want. For instance, you could extract `x` and `y` from `a` as shape `A x 1` via [`hsplit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hsplit.html#numpy.hsplit), then [`hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) them back to a `A x 2` array:

```
>>> a = np.arange(20).reshape(10, 2)

>>> def toPolar(arr):
...     x, y = np.hsplit(arr, 2)
...     return np.hstack([np.hypot(y, x), np.arctan2(y, x)])

>>> toPolar(a)
array([[ 1.        ,  1.57079633],
       [ 3.60555128,  0.98279372],
       [ 6.40312424,  0.89605538],
       [ 9.21954446,  0.86217005],
       [12.04159458,  0.84415399],
       [14.86606875,  0.83298127],
       [17.69180601,  0.82537685],
       [20.51828453,  0.81986726],
       [23.34523506,  0.81569192],
       [26.17250466,  0.81241861]])
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is use `numpy` functions, and not `vectorize`:

```
In [109]: def rect2polar(x, y):
     ...:         r = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
                  # r=np.hypot(x,y) # faster
     ...:         ang = np.arctan2(y, x)
     ...:         return (r, ang)
     ...: 
In [110]: rect2polar(arr[:,0],arr[:,1])
Out[110]: 
(array([ 1.        ,  3.60555128,  6.40312424,  9.21954446, 12.04159458,
        14.86606875, 17.69180601, 20.51828453, 23.34523506, 26.17250466]),
 array([1.57079633, 0.98279372, 0.89605538, 0.86217005, 0.84415399,
        0.83298127, 0.82537685, 0.81986726, 0.81569192, 0.81241861]))
```

The result is 2 arrays, but those are easily combined with `np.transpose`:

```
In [111]: np.transpose(rect2polar(arr[:,0],arr[:,1]))
Out[111]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  1.57079633],
       [ 3.60555128,  0.98279372],
       [ 6.40312424,  0.89605538],
       [ 9.21954446,  0.86217005],
       [12.04159458,  0.84415399],
       [14.86606875,  0.83298127],
       [17.69180601,  0.82537685],
       [20.51828453,  0.81986726],
       [23.34523506,  0.81569192],
       [26.17250466,  0.81241861]])
```

By the way, `np.argwhere` uses the same trick to turn the `np.nonzero` arrays into a one.

Another way to get `x,y` is `x,y = arr.T`.  Looking at `x.base` we see that `x` is just a `view` of the original `arange`.  So it's efficient.

Another way of combining the result arrays is:
`np.array(rect2polar(arr[:,0],arr[:,1])).T`.  This is slightly faster.  But compared to your `math` and `vectorize` version, any of these combination methods is fast.

With the `math` functions, your use of `vectorize` is slower than the straightforward list comprehension:

```
np.array([rect2polar(i,j) for i,j in zip(x,y)])
```

As a general rule `math` functions are faster than the equivalent `np` for single numbers.  But for arrays the `np` are faster.  Though the cross over point can will vary.